# Make CLI command compatible as pipe

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am using [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) to create CLI tool.
I want to create a command that can be pipeable.

For example, 
`echo 'Hello world' | customcmd > hello.txt`

where **customcmd** is a command which takes a stdin input and returns stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Put a shebang at 1st line of the customcmd file:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

and set the executable bit:

```
$ chmod a+x customcmd
```

Then you'll be good to go, e.g. `$ echo Hello | ./customcmd`

cf [exec](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve)

Comment: `./` or other valid relative or absolute path will be required unless `customcmd` is in your `$PATH`.  You can also do the very same thing without the shebang line `#!...` and `chmod` by running python , which works the same: `echo Hello | python ./customcmd`

Comment: Thanks for the reply and resource. Just a quick question. If the CLI tool is a group of commands and I just want to make one sub-command pipeable, will this be the way to do it?

Comment: You'll have to go out of your way to make only one of your executions pipeable.  The power of shell redirection (file redirection, pipes etc) is that the program doesn't care where it's input comes from or output goes, so it's flexible.  To remove your application's flexibility, you'll have to ascertain whether stdin is a pipe and act accordingly.  I recommand going in the opposite direction - make all program components take input from any stdin stream the invoker cares to provide,  Input prompts are popular in academia but very rare in the real world; synchronized user input is inconvenient.